# QGIS crashes when opening *.qgs file created with previous version?

Tags: qgis, installation

I've upgraded QGIS to version 2.12.x (I tried both 2.12.2 and 2.12.4 versions) on Windows 7 x86-64.

QGIS crashes with the message 'minidump written to C:..." each time I try to load a .qgs file which has been created with a previous version.
However, there is no problem when I launch qgis-browser without opening the file.

The problem doesn't seem to come from the newer version, nor from the .qgis file because :

- the .qgis file can be opened from an other computer running the version 2.12.2,
- the .qgis file can be opened on the same computer but with an other Windows user account.

This led me to search the problem in my Windows user profile.
I tried to backup then remove all folders related to qgis in my user profile (.qgis, .qgis2, .matplotlib, .designer), but this has not solved the problem  :(

Is it possible that problem stems from my user registry ?

Assuming yes, what is the better way to solve it ?
Should I backup my NTUSER.DAT hive and then clean my user registry ?

Assuming yes, are there other keys than "HKEY_CURRENT_USERS\Software\QGIS" to delete ?

Answer (score 1):

Before cleaning the registry, you can try switching from QGIS standalone to OSGEO4W Network installer. Both install separately.

Or unistall QGIS before reinstalling.

Comment: Thanks for your help.

The problem concern a corporate computer.
I can suggest an updgrade or a downgrade of the software, but I can't replace it by an other software.

I already tried to downgrade to the previously installed version (2.8.X) and to uninstall then reinstall the 2.12.x version. But neither downgrading nor reinstalling the software have solved the problem.

Thibault